# How I can reset all of desktop configuration without reinstall it?

Tags: 12.04

Excuse me, I have some duty from my teachers to make tutorial video by records how to change and setting desktop configuration. The problem is, I have been setting all my desktop configuration. Is that any way to reset it without reinstall?
Thanks before

Comment: Define "reset". Does that include removing any files you might have saved on your desktop?

Comment: A duty from teachers is usually called homework, is it not?

Comment: @mikewhatever yes, but I think the OP is not asking for help on the homework bit. The homework is setting up the desktop so the OP wants to revert to a freshly installed desktop so they can perform the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

The command

```
unity --reset
```

reverts your desktop settings back to default. Also,

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure unity
```

may help.